# bash bad interpreter permission denied

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, java

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm trying to execute a single-file java code

```
./SingleFileSource
```

I get the following error

```
bash: ./SingleFileSource: /usr/bin/java: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

I tried

```
chmod +rwx SingleFileSource
chmod +rwx /usr/bin/java
```

also tried to execute it as `root` but I'm getting the same error

On my previous Ubuntu 20.04 I was able to execute the code and I don't remember if I ever had to set any permissions explicitly.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message indicates bash is having a problem with the "shebang" in the script... i.e. the first line which indicates the command interpreter.  Further, the message indicates you are trying to use    /usr/bin/java.... [This Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shebang-scripts.html) indicates you should specify the path to the JDK... is /usr/bin/java the JDK??   If it is, then perhaps you should add the contents of SingleFileSource to your question.

Comment: Yes, my JDK is at ```usr/bin/java``` and the shebang is ```#!/usr/bin/java --source 17```
I'm not sure if the content matters, it's a simple class with a main method and some functions

Comment: @TonyB What is interesting, if I rename the file with .java, remove the shebang and run it like java SingleFileSource.java it executes.

Comment: can you put output of `which java`? can you confirm that output is the same as `/usr/bin/java`? that doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm not a Java maven, but the link I gave you shows and example that ends:  "--source 11"  Could that be the problem?  And as @Esther requested, could you provide the output of "which java" and confirm that output is the same as "/usr/bin/java"

Comment: @Esther @TonyB Thanks! ```Which java``` solved the issue, usr/bin/java was not the correct path, I only had a copy of the jdk in usr/bin/java